# Significance of the complex conjugation symmetry of the DFT for real-valued input

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

For real-valued input $\mathbf{x} = (x_0, ..., x_{N-1})$ and its discrete Fourier transform (DFT) $\mathbf{X} = \mathcal{F}(\mathbf{x})$ we have that

$$X_{N-k} = X_k^*$$

where * denotes complex conjugation.

As an example of the consequences of this, consider the function $f(t) = \sin(20*2*\pi*t)$. This could be thought of as a signal oscillating at a frequency of $20$ Hz. If I were to sample this signal at a rate of $100$ Hz, and then DFT these samples into Fourier coefficients, I would find a non-zero coefficient corresponding to $20$ Hz and another coefficient of equal magnitude corresponding to $80$ Hz (and zero everywhere else).

Is there a non-mathematical reason to expect this? Is there any meaning, physical or otherwise, that can be given to the coefficient corresponding to $80$ Hz? Is there some property of the input signal that oscillates at $80$ Hz, or some interpretation that would make it seem to be, or is it just a mathematical artifact?

Comment: the coefficients at the harmonics of the fundamental frequency $n \times 20Hz$ (with $n$ an integer $\ge 2$) can be very low if the signal is a pure sine and that it is [correctly windowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). see this image http://electronicdesign.com/site-files/electronicdesign.com/files/uploads/2013/11/0114GettingTheSignalFig4.gif the bottom signal is a pure sine correctly windowed, and its DFT will be nearly a pure peak at the fundamental frequency

Comment: for really understanding how windowing affects the spectrum, you'll need at the very least to study the Fourier series, and probably also the Fourier transform.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In my example it is purely a coincidence that $80 = 4*20$, the function $f(t) = \sin(19*2*\pi*t)$ would have Fourier coefficients of equal magnitude at $19$ Hz and $81$ Hz.

It is a mathematical fact that there is a power peak at $20$ Hz and $80$ Hz, even after windowing the magnitude of the peak at $80$ Hz must be equal to the magnitude of the peak at $20$ Hz.

Comment: ah sorry I didn't get the point, that you were asking about the negative frequencies, not the harmonics. yes it is because the pure waves are complex exponentials $e^{2 i \pi f_0 t}$ not sines, hence $\displaystyle \sin(2 \pi f_0 t) = \frac{e^{2 i \pi f_0 t} - e^{-2 i \pi f_0 t}}{2 i}$ and its Fourier transform will have two peaks at $\pm f_0$. when you sample at $F_s \ Hz$, the frequencies become modulo $Fs$, since $g(t) = e^{2 i \pi k F_s t}$ becomes $g(n) = 1$ after sampling. hence the spectrum of $\sin(2 \pi f_0 t)$ after sampling will have peaks at $n F_s \pm f_0, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: and do you know what is an unitary/orthonormal matrix ? the discrete Fourier transform can be seen as [an unitary matrix whose rows/columns are complex exponentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT)

Comment: final reason for the complex exponentials to be better than sines : the energy of a pure complex exponential is constant, the energy just rotates around the time axis, where a sine, its energy  "disappears at each period" oscillating from potential energy to kinetic energy all the time. hence complex exponentials have a very good physical meaning that sines don't have (for example you can think to the real part as the kinetic energy, and the imaginary part as the potential energy...)